# How can I map class types to instances of that class in C++?

Tags: c++, types, dictionary

I wish to have a map from classes to instances of each class. The goal is to have a container of components for a component-based game engine where an object can have at most one of each component type.

In Java, I could just use class objects as the key. How can I do something similar in C++? My initial research suggests something like using typeid(component_instance).name() as the key. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest that you are using the wrong approach.

Comment: Sounds like a classical case of "describe the problem, not what you imagined to be the solution".

Comment: Rather than using the name() (which isn't guaranteed to be unique), you can wrap the type_info with something that passes around pointers to them, and uses it's `less()` method to compare them.  Or, if you're using C++11, you can use `type_index` which is a standard version of what I just described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in more dynamic languages like Python or Java, classes in C++ are not objects themselves. At runtime they merely do not exist (as for a programmers point of view).

Your `typeid` approach is not that bad, but for performance issues I'd use a hash or a numeric ID (like an integer defined as static in your class) instead of the string.

Comment: I like the static integer ID idea; I guess it's just up to me to ensure that each ID is unique?

Comment: It's fairly easy to generate "unique" id's, if they don't have to be persistent.  Use a static instance for each id, with ` = getNextId();` as an initializer, and `int getNextId() { static int id = 0; return ++ id; }`.

Comment: @Jake: I thought of static (compile time) string hashes generated from the class-name. (e.g: http://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/hashed-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

**C++ classes are not [reified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29)** so you don't have class objects.

You might consider having your own class descriptors (as a convention). You could even make your own preprocessor for that.

Perhaps you could study and take inspiration from Qt [meta-object system](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html), which uses a preprocessor called [moc](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html). Probably, using exactly Qt objects is simpler than inventing your own meta-class system.

Answer (score 1):

You could create unique keys for types like this (note that this is for single-threaded execution only):

```
struct TypeManager
{
  private:
    static int next_id(void)
    {
        static int id = 0;
        return ++id;
    }
  public:
    template<typename T>
    static int get_type_id(void)
    {
        static int const id = next_id();
        return id;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int unique_bool_id = TypeManager::get_type_id<bool>();
int unique_float_id = TypeManager::get_type_id<float>();
```

Comment: or use [`typeid`/`type_info`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/) without relying on undefined behaviour (you even assume that function pointers and integers have the same size).

Comment: @phresnel: That's my thought. This looked like a bad re-implementation of `typeid`. Why not just use `typeid` directly? You can use the name field as a key if you need to.

Comment: @Baltram: I fixed your code so it was actually correct. This does have the advantage of actually working in a single-threaded environment.

Comment: @Baltram: Nice idea, however that's not thread safe and still re-inventing wheels.

Comment: @Omnifarious Thank you (forgot to put `return id;` at the end of the function). However I liked it slightly better the other way round (`if (id) return id;`) (-;

Comment: @Omnifarious: You can get away without the conditional, because the object is initialised only once :)

Comment: @phresnel You're right, it's for single-threaded applications only. But wouldn't it be faster than typeid(int).name()? I gueess it would.

Comment: @Baltram: It probably is faster, indeed (let me add a disclaimer)

Comment: @Omnifarious `typeid/type_info` does not give any guarantees. It may return identical ids for different types. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA, a Singleton class ensures a class has only one instance.

Also in C++, if you want to create only one instance of a class then the Singleton patterns are used. 
The Singleton Design pattern is used, where only one instance of an object is needed throughout the lifetime of an application.

The Singleton class is instantiated at the time of first access and same instance is used thereafter till the application quits.

The Singleton Design pattern is often used to control access to resources such as database connections or sockets. Suppose we have a license for only one connection for our database. A Singleton connection object makes sure that only one connection can be made at any time.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
private:
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static Singleton *single;
    Singleton()
    {
        //private constructor

    }
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance();
    void method();
    ~Singleton()
    {
        instanceFlag = false;
    }
};

bool Singleton::instanceFlag = false;
Singleton* Singleton::single = NULL;

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
{
    if(! instanceFlag)  // use the instanceFlag in all methods and functions to check if object already exists 
    {
        single = new Singleton();
        instanceFlag = true;
        cout<<"NO OBJECT WAS PREVIOUSLY CREATED"<< endl;
        cout<<"__________________________________________________"<< endl;

        return single;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"OBJECT ALREADY EXISTS!!"<< endl;
        cout<<"__________________________________________________"<< endl;
        return single;
    }
}

void Singleton::method()
{
     cout << "Method of the singleton class" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Singleton *sc1,*sc2;
    cout<<"Object 1"<< endl;
    sc1 = Singleton::getInstance(); 
    cout<<"Object 2"<< endl;
    sc2 = Singleton::getInstance(); 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to ensure that each class has only one instance, I want a collection which contains objects inheriting from a base class, and which contains only one instance of each subclass that's been added so far.