# C++ - Is there a way that using Class name as a key of std::map?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use class as a key of standard map structure.

The usage is like below.

```
std::map<ClassName, int> someMap;

someMap[ StudentClass ]
someMap[ TeacherClass ]
```

I'll use this making Template Factory class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I map class types to instances of that class in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562994/how-can-i-map-class-types-to-instances-of-that-class-in-c)

Comment: This question keeps on popping up in various form. I've seen it at least 3 times in the past few months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need the class names to be human reaqdable? If not, then you can use `typeid` and `type_info`. You can get the string with `type_info::name()` ([details](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)), but note that it is not guaranteed to be anything readable or even unique, for that matter (the `type_info` object itself, however, is going to be unique). Beyond that, you'll have to either rely on non-portable mechanisms or write your own code for doing this.

Comment: "not guaranteed to be anything readable" understates the issue a little - it is allowed to be simply `[ NUL ]`, or the same for distinct types, which implies potential robustness / portability issues with using it for this purpose.

Comment: Tony is correct, there is no requirement on what `name` provides. To alleviate this you can simply use the `type_info` itself as the key. It has a `before` function which provides a natural ordering to the types.

Answer (score 2):

The best bet would be to use, `typeid()`. It will give you the uniqueness across classes. However, you cannot retrieve the class type from typeid automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of Microsoft-specific, but I think you could use [__uuidof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
std::map<GUID, int> someMap;
someMap[__uuidof(StudentClass)] = 1;
someMap[__uuidof(TeacherClass)] = 2;
someMap[__uuidof(ClassClass)] = 3;
```

There is probably a better way you could do this using a C++ virtual class variable or something like that.

Comment: Why not use `typeid` or `std::type_info::name`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use typeid(SomeObject).name(), but it is not portable between compilers. if what you are developing is a library or portable code and you really need a readable "class name", you may write a "meta class" for every class.

```
template<typename T> class MetaClass{};
class Foobar {
//...
};
template<> class MetaClass<Foobar> {
public:
    static std::string className() {
        return "Foobar";
    }
};
std::map<std::string, int> someMap;
someMap[MetaClass<Foobar>::className()] = 0xff;
//...
```

If you don't like template, you may implement it in some other way, for example virtual method.